# Count rows according to 2 column with Group By

Tags: sql

I have a database table of 3 columns

```
RecordID    Deleted CardHolderID
1963        1       9
4601        1       9
6996        0       9
1532        1      11
1529        0      20
```

I want an sql query to output the sum of rows of Deleted column grouped by CardHolderID.

However query below outputs 2 columns for CardHolderID

```
select c.CardHolderID, c.Deleted, COUNT(*) as Sum 
from Card c 
group by c.Deleted, c.CardHolderID

CardHolderID    Deleted Sum
9               0       1
9               1       2
20              0       1
11              1       1
```

I want to include 2 columns as **Deleted0 (count of rows with Deleted column equal to 0)** and **Deleted1 (count of rows with Deleted column equal to 1)**

```
CardHolderID    Deleted0 Deleted1
9               1       2
20              1       0
11              1       1
```

How should be the SQL query for such a result?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional count:

```
select c.CardHolderID, 
   count( case when c.deleted > 0 then 1 else null end ) deleted0, 
   count( case when c.deleted = 0 then 1 else null end ) deleted1, 
from Card c 
group by c.CardHolderID
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` CardHolderID alone.

Use `SUM(Deleted)` to count the 1's.

Use `SUM(1-deleted)` to count the 0's.

```
select c.CardHolderID, sum(1-c.deleted) deleted0, sum(c.Deleted) deleted1
from Card c 
group by c.CardHolderID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer jarlh . Is there a way to count the rows instead of sum? Because there would be values 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: It can be done. Either ask a new question, or edit this one to reflect those requirements. And add a tag for the dbms you're using, because the answer will be product specific.

Comment: Thank you again, this answer above solves my problem for now. I'll post another question for count case. Could it be done with a simple sql query? I'm using SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server, check out PIVOT!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MSSQL

```
select DtlPivot.CardHolderID, isnull(DtlPivot.[0],0) as Deleted0, isnull(DtlPivot.[1],0) as Deleted1 from
(
    select c.CardHolderID, c.Deleted, COUNT(*) as Total from Card c 
    group by c.Deleted, c.CardHolderID
) aa
PIVOT
(
    sum(Total) FOR Deleted IN([0],[1])
)AS DtlPivot
```